# How to open application from browser on Mac OS X?

Tags: oauth, callback, openurl

I'm doing a Twitter Mac OS X app and need to use OAuth1.0. When requesting oauth/access_token interface, is it possible to use the `oauth_callback` parameter for this purpose?

In other words how to open application from browser on the Max OS X?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is obvious: register the custom URL scheme

http://techblog.amphora-research.com/2010/03/registering-url-handlers-in-macos-x-cocoa-apps/

What I mean:

```
 1. Register the "twittercallbackformyapp://"
    scheme using the link above
 2. Set this callback in the 'access_token'
    HTTP request (oauth_callback parameter)
 3. Write the routine (handleOpenURL) to handle
    the 'twittercallbackformyapp://oauth_access_token=...&oauth_token_secret=...'
    which will be called after you register the handler
```

Many questions regarding oauth are solved here: http://code.google.com/p/twitcurl/

The lib above uses curl. You can use the Cocoa native networking APIs.

P.S.

Here's another description on how to register the URL handler:

http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

It is for iPhone, but for Mac the pattern is the same: add the URL to your app's .plist file.

Comment: Of course, the actual OAuth hashes and responses require extra work.

Comment: I've spent a lot of time with these issues myself. Glad if this helps you.

Comment: :), I found a very good third-party network framework, http://www.chilkatsoft.com/,  but it's not free, do you know a Free good third-party frameworks, it must  can be  setting proxy.

Comment: curl and specifically twitcurl which I've mentioned support proxies.